# How to adjust microphone sensitivity [not volume] using Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-audio-api

i would like to achieve in the same way discord app is doing, calibrate the audio input to be triggered at a certain volume (Decibel, ...) and not bellow that volume.

[image: discord sensitivity]

I'm creating a video call app and i want before the call allow the user to setup his devices correctly. Actually the sensitivity is too high and there is a lot of undesirable noise (You can even hear a bug fly).

I did a lot of unsuccessful research about how to achieve this with the Web Audio API.

At the beginning i tried to use the [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/GainNode) but it's just a way to amplify/attenuate (+/-) the sound like a volume.

After i tried using the [BiquadFilterNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode) but it's just some filters to attenuate/amplify the audio around a certain frequency.

I think there is maybe a way using [AudioWorklet](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#audioworklet) but i don't find any clear documentation about how to solve my problem.

I would like in the same way i'm modifying the gain create a function `setVolumeThreshold` that regarding a certain db (or other kind of value) cut the sound bellow that.

```
var start = () => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
  .then(stream => audio.srcObject = modifyGain(stream, 2.5))
  .catch(e => log(e));

var modifyGain = (stream, gainValue) => {
  var ctx = new AudioContext();
  var src = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  var dst = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
  var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
  gainNode.gain.value = gainValue;
  [src, gainNode, dst].reduce((a, b) => a && a.connect(b));
  return dst.stream;
};
```

Here a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmhrd1rt/) using that code snippet.

Thanks a lot to those will try to help me !

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar project quite a while ago using ScriptProcessorNode - https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter/.  It should be easily portable to AudioWorklet. 
 Also of interest is the "noise gate" effect in https://github.com/cwilso/Audio-Input-Effects, which I think is closer to what you want?

Comment: I already found your snippet before and it was interesting indeed but it's a visualisation of the volume and i don't see how using/based-on your code i could no let pass the sound input on a certain volume. Do you have any idea ? Thx a lot for the "Noise Gate" link i'll try it soon :)